# Use cell with filename as value to 'link' to external sheet

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, external-data

I have an excel workbook with a sheet called Data where some filenames from other workbooks are stored.
I want to refer to a cell from another workbook which filename I have saved in that sheet mentioned above.
Sheet with filenames in cells: Data
Cell with filename I need: A2 in Data
Sheet I need from other file: inv05
Cell I want to read: E7

So i thought it has to work like this:

`='["&Data!$A$2&"]inv05'!$E$7`

Use the standard formula and exclude with " the filename cell. But it don't work.

Can somebody help?

DHB

Comment: [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) and [ADDRESS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ADDRESS-function-d0c26c0d-3991-446b-8de4-ab46431d4f89) are your friends

Comment: But INDIRECT needs opened Workbooks, is there no other solution with closed workbooks?

Comment: Ouch.  No, I don't think so.  You can't copy the relevant sheet to an open workbook?

Comment: I could, but the idea behind this is:
I have some sales data from different month, the filename of the workbooks changes from month to month. i.e. data0617 for data from June 2017.
So I want to make an information sheet to print the important information of each month. But I only want to create this sheet one time, and then I just can change the filename in that cell mentioned.
Sure, open the file with the data is only one step more, but it don't feel perfect, if you know what I mean.

Comment: If the filenames are consistently structured, you could just use the date to work out which sheet you want opened.  Something like `Concatenate("Data" + Month(Now()) + Year(Now()))` or similar should work

Comment: Yeah.
I have concatenated ( :) ) it:
`=CONCATENATE("='[";Data!$A$2;"]";"inv05'!$E$13")`
But how to use it as a formula? 
Sorry for so many questions.